# Replace little text format hashtag in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string returned by the LinkedIn API that contains a number of hashtags. They are formatted like this:

```
{hashtag|\#|somehashtag}
```

I am trying to use a regex with `String.replaceAll` that will replace all occurrence of these hashtags to a standard hashtag notation like this:

```
#somehashtag
```

I think this regex will identify the hashtags in the string, but how do I identify what would replace it as the second parameter?

```
mystring.replaceAll(/(?<={hashtag\|\\\#\|)(.*)(?=})/g, /* whatgoeshere? */ );
```

So for example, if I have:

```
var mystring = "This is my social post, and it has a hashtag in it like this {hashtag|\#|somehashtag} and I want it replaced";
```

I want to be able to run something like:

```
mystring = mystring.replaceAll(regex, replacement)
```

So that this is returned in mystring:

```
"This is my social post, and it has a hashtag in it like this #somehashtag and I want it replaced"
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question with some example inputs / outputs?

Comment: You could try [`{hashtag\|\\\#\|(.*?)}` with substitution of `#$1`](https://regex101.com/r/J1LdeM/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capturing group *[`(.*?)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Capturing_group)* that captures the actual hashtag text. And in the second parameter to `replace` use the captured group using `$1` along with `#`.

```js
const regex = /{hashtag\|\\\#\|(.*?)}/g;
/* If it is a word character and that you're sure. 
 You can also use \w(matches [0-9a-zA-Z_]).
 so /{hashtag\|\\\#\|(\w*?)}/g
 https://regex101.com/r/zDTH6B/1 */
const mystring = "This is a {hashtag|\\#|samplehashtag} and another {hashtag|\\#|examplehashtag} in the text.";
const replaced = mystring.replace(regex, '#$1');

console.log(replaced);
```